# Select records where every record in one-to-many join matches a condition

Tags: sql, ruby

How can I write a SQL query that returns records from table `A` *only if* **every** associated record from table `B` matches a condition?

I'm working in Ruby, and I can encode this logic for a simple collection like so:

```
array_of_A.select { |a| a.associated_bs.all? { |b| b.matches_condition? } }
```

I am being generic in the construction, because I'm working on a general tool that will be used across a number of distinct situations.

What I know to be the case is that `INNER JOIN` is the equivalent of

```
array_of_A.select { |a| a.associated_bs.any? { |b| b.matches_condition? } }
```

I have tried both:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "A".* FROM "A"
INNER JOIN "B"
  ON "B"."a_id" = "A"."id"
WHERE "B"."string' = 'STRING'
```

as well as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "A".* FROM "A"
INNER JOIN "B"
  ON "B"."a_id" = "A"."id"
  AND "B"."string' = 'STRING'
```

In both cases (as I expected), it returned records from table `A` if **any** associated record from `B` matched the condition. I'm sure there's a relatively simple solution, but my understanding of SQL just isn't providing it to me at the moment. And all of my searching thru SO and Google has proven fruitless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
select distinct a.* 
from a inner join 
(
    select b.a_id 
    from b 
    group by b.a_id 
    having min(b.string) = max(b.string) and min(b.string) = 'string'
) c on a.id = c.a_id
```

Alternatively:

```
select distinct a.* 
from a inner join b on a.id = b.a_id
where not exists (select 1 from b c where c.a_id = a.id and c.string <> 'string')
```

**Note:** In the above examples, only change the symbols `a` and `b` to the names of your tables; the other identifiers are merely aliases and should not be changed.